# linux shell installing packages automaticc

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos, administration

I want to install packages automatically by running a script

I can write

```
 yum install php
```

but I want it to install another package once installation of the php package is completed

Is  there any solution to make it automatic?

I have around 20packages which are to be downloaded from remi repository

Comment: You mean `yum` doesn't accept `yum install <package> <package> <package>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write your script named `installer.sh` as:

```
#!/bin/bash
yum -y install php
yum -y install <another_package>
yum -y install <yet_another_package>
...
```

Then run it `$ bash installer.sh`

Comment: it wont be done automatic, because it will prompt for Yes/No and user has to type in Y inorder to continue, Is there a way to do it automatic without need of user

Comment: @meWantToLearn in that case use `-y` option, see the updated answer